# When are Linear functions on normed spaces continuous? And what Properties do they have?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, soft-question

In Analysis and Linear Algebra classes one always talks about linear function and continuous function somewhat separately... so that let me to:

Suppose $(V,\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_V)$ and $(W,\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert_W)$ are a normed vector space and $f:V \rightarrow W$ is an linear function. Since $V$ and $W$ are normed we can talk about the topology of $V$ and $W$ given by the open sets $B_V(x,r)=\{y \in V \mid \left\lVert x-y \right\rVert_V < r\}$ and  $B_W(x,r)=\{y \in W \mid \left\lVert x-y \right\rVert_W < r\}.$ For the continuity of $f$ we say that $f$ is continous at $x_0$ if:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0  \ \forall x \in V \ \exists \delta(\varepsilon,x):\left\lVert x_0-x \right\rVert_V< \delta \Rightarrow \left\lVert f(x_0)-f(x) \right\rVert_W < \varepsilon.$$ Since $f$ linear we get from above $\left\lVert x_0-x \right\rVert_V< \delta \Rightarrow \left\lVert f(x_0-x) \right\rVert_W < \varepsilon$. So from that I see that the identify function is continuous, and orthogonal function as-well, since $\left\lVert v \right\rVert_V = \left\lVert f(v) \right\rVert_W$ thus set $\delta = \varepsilon$ (its even uniformal continuous).

> My Question: Does $f$ need any additional property to be continuous or is linearity enought?  What kind of property are sufficient ? and if $f$ is linear and continous what does that say about $f$? For example the orthogonality above. And last but not least, does the dimension matter, are finite and infinite case the different?

> My Backround: Undergrade maths student. I know some linear Algebra asswell as Analysis and Topology but nothing yet about functional Analysis

Comment: A linear function $f : V \to W$ is continuous if and only if $$\sup_{\|v\|_V = 1} \|fv\|_W < \infty.$$ If $V$ is finite dimensional every linear $f$ must be continuous, but not so in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: So if understand this correctly in the infinite case, in order $f$ to be continuous has to be bounded regarding the supremum norm ?

Comment: Yes. Bounded iff continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$

1. $T$ is continuous.
2. $T$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$
3. $T$ is continuous at $0$
4. $\exists M>0$ such that $\forall x\in X$ $\|Tx\|\le M\|x\|$
5. $T(B[0, 1]) $ is bounded.
6. $T$ map bounded set to bounded set.

All the statements $(1) \to (6) $ are equivalent.

Examples: (continuous)

1. $\operatorname{Tr}: \mathcal{M_n(\Bbb{K}) }\to K$ defined by $$\operatorname{Tr}(A) =\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ii}$$
2. $Id :( C[0, 1], \|.\|_{\infty})\to ( C[0, 1], \|.\|_1)$

$$Id(f) =f$$

3. $I:(\mathcal{R}[a, b], \|•\|) \to \Bbb{R}$
   $$I(f) =\int_{a}^{b}f(t) dt$$

---

Examples: (not continuous)

1. $Id :( C[0, 1], \|.\|_{\infty})\to ( C[0, 1], \|.\|_1)$
   $$Id(f) =f$$
2. $T_0 :( C^1 [-\pi, \pi], \|.\|_{\infty})\to \Bbb{R}$

$$T_0(f) =f'(0) $$

---

All the above discontinuous linear map defined on a infinite dimensional normed linear space!

Another condition (sufficient but not necessary) for continuity $\dim(X) <\infty$

All linear maps that we have already studied in Linear algebra (finite dimensional analysis) is continuous!

---

To check the continuity of a linear map we only need to check whether it is continuous at $0$ or not,  locally continuous iff globally continuous ( sequence gives an easy characterization) , an ordinary map doesn't enjoy this property. For an example
$f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\in\Bbb{Q}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

continuous only at $0$ .

**For a linear map either it is continuous on the whole domain or it is discontinuous on the whole domain.**

---

**Linear maps defined between two normed linear spaces are just special, I like very much!**  (Lost in space)